# Error when compiling project in Avr Studio 6

Tags: avr, atmel, atmega

I am getting the following error when buildign my project in AVR Studio 6:
`400  Id returned 1 exit status  collect2.exe`

And if I look at my output I have the following:

```
Building target: main.elf
    Invoking: AVR/GNU Linker : 3.4.2
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.2.1002\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe" -o main.elf  eeprom.o panel6.o testmode.o uart.o AT45DB161.o delay.o dtmf.o keypad.o lcd.o main.o mcu.o menu.o remote_rx.o spi.o tx75x.o bootloader.o txcellular.o   -Wl,-Map="main.map" -Wl,--start-group  -Wl,--end-group -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega64 
    c:/program files (x86)/atmel/atmel toolchain/avr8 gcc/native/3.4.2.1002/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.7.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a(cmpsf2.o):/data2/home/toolsbuild/jenkins-knuth/workspace/avr8-gnu-toolchain/src/avr-libc/libm/fplib/cmpsf2.S:58: multiple definition of `__ltsf2'
    c:/program files (x86)/atmel/atmel toolchain/avr8 gcc/native/3.4.2.1002/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.7.2/avr5\libgcc.a(_lt_sf.o):/data2/home/toolsbuild/jenkins-knuth/workspace/avr8-gnu-toolchain/src/gcc/libgcc/fp-bit.c:1269: first defined here
    c:/program files (x86)/atmel/atmel toolchain/avr8 gcc/native/3.4.2.1002/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.7.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a(cmpsf2.o):/data2/home/toolsbuild/jenkins-knuth/workspace/avr8-gnu-toolchain/src/avr-libc/libm/fplib/cmpsf2.S:58: multiple definition of `__lesf2'
    c:/program files (x86)/atmel/atmel toolchain/avr8 gcc/native/3.4.2.1002/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.7.2/avr5\libgcc.a(_le_sf.o):/data2/home/toolsbuild/jenkins-knuth/workspace/avr8-gnu-toolchain/src/gcc/libgcc/fp-bit.c:1290: first defined here

collect2.exe(0,0): ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main.elf] Error 1
The command exited with code 2.


Done executing task "RunCompilerTask" -- FAILED.
Done building target "CoreRebuild" in project "main.cproj" -- FAILED.
Done building project "main.cproj" -- FAILED.
```

The main error which sticks out is:  `multiple definition of __lesf2'`
I am very new to AVR could some one please help me out here.

Comment: The __lesf2 function is in the floating point library. Either you are not linking the library correctly, or there are incompatible defines causing more than one version of the function to be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I did eventually figure out what was wrong so I just wanted to say what I did so if some one else every has the same issue they know what to do.

It was Actually quite a simple fix.

All I needed to do was go to the project properties, linker , libraries and then add "limb" to the lib. (mine was blank originally)

Here is a picture of what it must look like.

[image]